# Duplicate Query in Microsoft Access or SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, duplicates

I have over 1,000 entries with duplicate values in an Access database. I want to create a column called Duplicate and set it to `true` if a record is **NOT THE FIRST ONE** with a particular value. This means, if the record is the first one with the value "Red Chair", the Duplicate field is set to `false`, but all subsequent records with value "Red Chair" will have the Duplicate field set to `true`.

How do I perform this query in Access?

*This database will be upsized to an SQL Server database*, so an option for me is to 'ignore' the duplicate records while retrieving the records in my SQL query. If this option is viable, I'd like to know how to do this in SQL as alternative. Thanks.

Comment: You have not posted any sample data. You have not even posted a schema. Finally, you have not posted the sql you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use subqueries. Try this

```
UPDATE Tabelle1 SET Tabelle1.b = 'Duplicate'
WHERE 
((Tabelle1.[ID] In 
 (SELECT Tabelle1.[ID] FROM Tabelle1 WHERE 
  ((Tabelle1.[a] In 
     (SELECT [a] FROM [Tabelle1] As Tmp GROUP BY [a] HAVING Count(*)>1 )
   )
  AND 
  (Tabelle1.[ID] Not In 
    (SELECT min([id]) FROM [Tabelle1] as grpid GROUP BY [a] HAVING Count(*)>1)
  ));
)));
```

Comment: +1 for faithfully including brackets the same way Access would.

Comment: @ta.speot.is you got me there. Still the easiest way to check if a query is valid in access: use the query editor. And Boom thats what happens. Of course you could edit most of them out ;)

Comment: @Johanness You are an absolute genius! Every line of your code is perfect. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this sql help u:

SELECT table.field, Count(table.field) AS test, IIf([test]>1,"TRUE","FALSE") AS check
FROM table
GROUP BY table.field, IIf([test]>1,"TRUE","FALSE");

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert on the Access dialect, but this adaptation of RJIGO's answer or something similar may also work and be more efficient:

```
UPDATE Tabelle1 SET
  b = 'Duplicate'
WHERE 
  Tabelle1.[ID] > (
    SELECT min([id])
    FROM [Tabelle1] as T2
    WHERE T2.[a] = Tabelle1.[a]
  );
```

Comment: That's much better than my approach. (and it works perfectly in access).